# Organic Keyword Data vs. SEO Queries in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

What is the difference between Keywords>Organic data and Search Engine Optimization>Queries data? Aren't they both showing (or in the case of Organic Keywords, not showing) keywords that visitors clicked to go to your URLs?

Answer (score 0):

Organic search data in the acquisition reports is the search term plucked from the referring search engine url that brought a visitor to the page and is connected to other data points (so for example for a provided search keywords you can see if it lead to a conversion).

SEO data are Google search keywords imported from Google Webmaster Tools. This report shows you what has been searched for in connection with your site (even if it didn't result in a visit) but is not really connected to other data points in your reports.

To be a bit more concise, organic keywords is what brings visitors to your site. SEO Queries is what makes your site show up in Googles search result pages.